# Why does lisp-interaction-mode exist, and do we ever need it?

Tags: elisp, emacs-lisp-mode

**Q:** Why does `lisp-interaction-mode` exist, and are there any reasons to use it instead of `emacs-lisp-mode`?

The [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Executing-Lisp.html) states that `emacs-lisp-mode` and `lisp-interaction-mode` are identical except that the latter binds `C-j` to `eval-print-last-sexp`.  Beyond that, ["all other commands in Lisp Interaction mode are the same as in Emacs Lisp mode."](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Interaction.html)  As far as I can tell, only the `*scratch*` buffer uses the latter mode.

It strikes me as odd that there is an entire mode that differs from another by only a single keybinding, so I presume I'm missing either some history or context.

So:

- Why does `lisp-interaction-mode` exist?
- Not counting the `C-j` keybinding, are there any circumstances in which it would be preferable to `emacs-lisp-mode`?
- Would there be any unexpected consequences to [changing the `*scratch*` buffer's mode to `emacs-lisp-mode`](http://emacsredux.com/blog/2014/07/25/configure-the-scratch-buffers-mode/)?

*The motivation for this question is that, right now, I'm binding keys twice (in the two modes) so that my `*scratch*` buffer behaves like buffers visiting `*.el` files.  If there's no practical reason to keep `lisp-interaction-mode` around, I'll just `(setq initial-major-mode 'emacs-lisp-mode)` and be done with it.*

Comment: Maybe you'll stop prepending every of your questions with "**Q:**" :)

Comment: You can use any major mode you like for `*scratch*`.

Comment: @nicael: **Q:** what's not to like about the **Q**?  You *wound* me, sir! ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unless you hate the `C-j` behaviour (and I'm sure most elisp authors find it handy), just keep things the way they are.

Define your keys for `lisp-mode-shared-map` instead of duplicating them for the mode-specific keymaps.

All of `lisp-mode-map`, `emacs-lisp-mode-map`, and `lisp-interaction-mode-map` have `lisp-mode-shared-map` as their parent keymap.

Answer (score 15):

A new derived mode is cheap: `lisp-interaction-mode` inherits from `emacs-lisp-mode`, its implementation is just a dozen lines of code or so.  It differs from `emacs-lisp-mode` in just the following ways:

- it has a different name;
- it has a different keymap;
- it has a different syntax table;
- it has an additional hook.

On the other hand, it shares its abbrev table with `emacs-lisp-mode`.

**Edit:** as noted by @phils in his answer (which see), the keymaps of `emacs-lisp-mode` and `lisp-interaction-mode` share a common parent, `lisp-mode-shared-map`.  There is therefore no reason to duplicate keybindings — just define them in `lisp-mode-shared-map`, and they will apply to both modes (and `lisp-mode` too, but that's probably fine).

> Would there be any unexpected consequences to changing the `*scratch*` buffer's mode to `emacs-lisp-mode`?

The most obvious consequence would be that `lisp-interaction-mode-hook` would no longer be run in the `*scratch*` buffer.

Comment: It has an *additional* hook. `emacs-lisp-mode-hook` runs for `lisp-interaction-mode` because [that's how derived modes work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19280851/how-to-keep-dir-local-variables-when-switching-major-modes/19295380#19295380). It *does* have a different keymap, but both elisp modes share the same parent keymap (`lisp-mode-shared-map`). It does have a separate syntax table, but it's identical to that of its parent mode (because it defers to the parent for setting it).

Comment: Darn, you're right.  Hopefully correct now.

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, I use `emacs-lisp-mode` in the `*scratch*` buffer myself. If I wish to evaluate something, I just do <kbd>C-x C-e</kbd>, with a <kbd>C-u</kbd> prefix when needed. I see no downside to this practice.

As to why the mode is there, it is just a few lines of lisp code in `elisp-mode.el`, and it's been there like *forever*, so removing it seems pointless.

Comment: I started doing this myself ages ago because I wanted `C-j` bound to `newline-and-indent`, but these days, as indentation happens more automatically, this is not a serious concern anymore. So if I hadn't already made this change long ago, I wouldn't bother with it now.

Comment: Me too, for what it's worth - have done so for a long time. Or I use a throwaway `*.el` file buffer.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the differences mentioned in the other answers, there is a small but major difference between 'lisp-interaction-mode' and 'emacs-lisp-mode', which is that in 'lisp-interaction-mode' lexical binding is activated by default (see the documention [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Lexical-Binding.html)).

So for the scratch buffer, using 'emacs-lisp-mode' does not automatically provide lexical binding (which may lead to some, 'unexpected' behavior).
And, therefore, maybe (I don't see any reason why not), if you are not using [auto-insert-mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/autotype/Autoinserting.html), it might be wise to use 'lisp-interaction-mode' in .el buffers also (or to be 'extra' aware that when you just create a new .el buffer, lexical binding, by default, is not activated automatically).

The documentation you are linking to mentions that all other commands are identical (not all other 'aspects' of the modes). B.t.w. I do think that the difference regarding lexical binding should be mentioned (again) in that section of the docs also.