# Warnings about malformed functions when using lexical-let

Tags: warning, let-binding, lexical-binding

I have the following function:

```lisp
(defun filter-repl-show-after (line-num)
  "Show lines after LINE-NUM."
  (filter-repl--foreach-line
   (lexical-let ((line-num line-num))
     (lambda ()
       (when (> (line-number-at-pos) line-num)
         (filter-repl--show-line))))))

(defun filter-repl--foreach-line (f)
  "Apply F to each line in the buffer."
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (not (eobp))
        (funcall f)
        (forward-line))))
```

The elisp linter is warning me that `‘(line-num line-num)’ is a malformed function`. The problem seems to be due to the lexical letter, because I don't get the warning with

```lisp
(defun filter-repl-show-after-tweaked (line-num)
  "Show lines after LINE-NUM."
  (filter-repl--foreach-line
     (lambda ()
       (when (> (line-number-at-pos) line-num)
         (filter-repl--show-line)))))
```

Is this warning a false positive and I avoid it if so?

## Regarding checkdoc demanding uppercase names in docstring

Repro M-x checkdoc on

```
(defun hello (f)
  "Say hello to 'f'."
)
```

Results in the followign message:

```
Argument ‘f’ should appear (as F) in the doc string (C-h,f,e,n,p,q)
```

Comment: You should activate [lexical binding](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Lexical-Binding.html) instead of using `lexical-let`. See https://nullprogram.com/blog/2016/12/22/

Comment: Yeah I guess that's one approach. I'm a bit hesitant about lexical-let because I have a habit of editting functions one at a tine and evaluating them and could get bugs because the file's lexical-let property gets forgotten.

Comment: Ah, you might be interested in [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/75400/26163).

Comment: Trivial doco tip: you are unnecessarily (and incorrectly) quoting argument names in your docstrings. Taking your second function above for example, you are telling Emacs to link to the documentation for a variable, function, macro, user option, face or other object called "F" (literally, in upper case), which presumably does not exist. Just leave your argument names uppercase but unquoted.

Comment: @PhilHudson that's what the checkdoc wants.... I don't know why. Is there a better linter? https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/emacs-lisp/checkdoc.el#L1815

Comment: @AttRigh Perhaps you are misinterpreting checkdoc's feedback. I'd be interested to see the checkdoc message that flags plain F (or similar) as needing quotes.

Comment: I've included a repro in my questions. Here's the message: `Argument ‘f’ should appear (as F) in the doc string (C-h,f,e,n,p,q)`

Comment: That message confirm Phil's point. and tells you to include the argument as an uppercase f (F) in the docstring (and Phil adds the info that you should also remove the quoted 'f' as a reference to the argument f).

Comment: Ah okay `' means links. Fine, I might as well use that standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The elisp linter is warning me that ‘(line-num line-num)’ is a malformed function.

The elisp linter is saying that the list `(line-num line-num)` doesn't make sense as a function object.  The reason it thinks it should be a function object is probably that it doesn't know that `lexical-let` is a macro, and also because it's the first item in the unquoted `((line-num line-num))` list.

After initially copying your first code block into my *scratch* buffer, I got the same "malformed function" warning (plus a warning stating that *"the function"* `lexical-let` doesn't appear to be defined).

If you add `(require 'cl)` above the code, both warnings disappear.  However, an additional warning appears, about the "cl" library being deprecated.

From at least Emacs 28 forward, `lexical-let` is only found in the (deprecated) "cl" library.  Based on the commentary to "cl-lib", it may have at one point been included in that (non-deprecated) library, but it isn't anymore.  So you might want to look for an alternative to using the `lexical-let` macro.